# Cloudant case_clause error when requesting document with certain revision

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

When replicating or requesting a document with a certain revision I am getting the following error ->

```
{
  "error": "case_clause",
  "reason": "{ok,[{ok,{doc,<<\"a8fa021299855487fde50e6ccf70a976\">>,\n.......}}]}
}
```

See full error in gist below:
https://gist.github.com/paulJordaan/6f83d5fb9519453f87e78ddd192040e3

When doing a get request for the document without supplying the rev I get the correct response:

```
GET -> https:CLOUDANT/DB/a8fa021299855487fde50e6ccf70a976
```

However when supplying the revision for this latest version of the stored doc I get the error mentioned above:

```
GET -> https:CLOUDANTDB/a8fa021299855487fde50e6ccf70a976?rev=3801-65391644310798d8b5970504ed9b9ca3
```

I've tried updating the document to get a new revision but the problem persists. I've also checked that the document in question contains no conflicts.

This error is causing my replication to mobile devices to fail which is a major issue. Does anyone have some information as to what could be causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have received a response from Cloudant's support team.

This is apparently a known issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-3193

If you encounter the same issue the Support team can run the necessary steps to resolve the problem.